# Iterating using a goroutine is giving unexpected result

Tags: loops, go, concurrency, goroutine

I was doing some condition checking inside the goroutine based on the iteratating variable `i` and found that it is giving me results that I wasn't expecting, and I decided to confirm it with some simple code.

```
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    fmt.Println(i)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println(i)
        wg.Done()
    }()


}
wg.Wait()

1
2
3
4
5
6
6
6
6
6
```

Is this expected behaviour? Could someone kindly explain why is 6 being printed for 5 times, though I was iterating only till 5??

Comment: Also see the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: Maybe a more exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776315/go-concurrency-with-for-loop-and-anonymous-function-behaves-unexpectedly

Comment: It's not necessary that you will get 6,6,6,6 only. Increase the value of i. You will get different value. You are getting the value of i at the time of execution of goroutine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bGU0UpMi-Z)

All your goroutines are running asynchronously **after** your for loop has finished.

At the end of your for loop `i` is equal to 6, and thus, your goroutines each log the number 6.

To fix the problem you can create a closure, and save the current value of `i` inside it so that when the goroutine runs, it runs with the proper value of `i`.

To do this just change your code so it looks like

```c
go func(x int) {
  fmt.Println(x)
  wg.Done()
}(i) // <--- "save" value of i at this point in time.
```

This way you "save" the value of `i` inside the function you're telling the goroutine to execute such that later, when the for loop has run to completion, it doesn't use the **current** value of `i` which is 6; instead, it uses the **old** value of `i` at the time the goroutine was created.